Miss Arrowpoint’s resemblance to a carte-de-visite in “Daniel Deronda” by George Eliot
From Daniel Deronda by George Eliot:

But to a mind of general benevolence, wishing everybody to look well, it was rather exasperating to see how Gwendolen eclipsed others: how even the handsome Miss Lawe, explained to be the daughter of Lady Lawe, looked suddenly broad, heavy and inanimate; and how Miss Arrowpoint, unfortunately also dressed in white, immediately resembled a carte-de-visite in which one would fancy the skirt alone to have been charged for. Since Miss Arrowpoint was generally liked for the amiable unpretending way in which she wore her fortunes, and made a softening screen for the oddities of her mother, there seemed to be some unfitness in Gwendolen’s looking so much more like a person of social importance.
George Eliot (1876). Daniel Deronda, book 1, chapter 5. Project Gutenberg.

A carte-de-visite was a small portrait photograph, the size of a visiting card.
In what way did Miss Arrowpoint resemble “a carte-de-visite in which one would fancy the skirt alone to have been charged for”? The remark seems intended to be witty or deprecating at Miss Arrowpoint’s expense, but how does it work?

It's not clear, but maybe her white dress had a very elaborate skirt (such as were fashionable in the Victorian era) which was the most conspicuous part of the picture?

The skirts in Victorian times were gathered and bustle skirts. The idea seems to be that it was probably voluminous, taking  up most of the picture frame...
